# Как настроить маршруты для ссылок для которых нет контролеров?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Есть ссылка вида http://site.com/RND/PARAMS 
Если стандартно то получается что RND - Контроллер, PARAMS - экшен.
Но у меня RND и PARAMS меняются.
Так же у меня есть `AccountController`, `AdminController` и тд, мне нужно что бы ссылки вида `http://site.com/Account` `http://site.com/Admin` обрабатывались этими контроллерами по стандарту.

```C#
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

А вот ссылки

```html
http://site.com/RND/PARAMS
http://site.com/RND/
http://site.com/123/PARAMS
http://site.com/abc/
http://site.com/zzzz/1124/23525/1233/5235
```

Обрабатывались в другом общем контроллере, например в `RedirectController` Где у меня бы был один экшен который бы принимал все параметры `/123/PARAMS` `/zzzz/1124/23525/1233/5235` и я уже там в зависимости от того какие и сколько параметров уже выбирал бы что дальше делать.
Как настроить такую маршрутизацию?
Извините за название вопроса, я хз как спросить, если у кого есть идеи то переименуйте или напишите комментарий я сам переименую.

Comment: а параметры GET запроса `?param1=value1&param2=value2` вам почему не подходят?

Comment: Ну вообще подходит но мне нужно через маршруты сделать.

Comment: Путь, если речь про REST - для сущностей, параметры - для параметров. То есть каждый `/X/` должен представлять из себя объект. Конкретизируйте вопрос. Например, я хочу получить третьего юзера `/Users/3/`, здесь все очевидно. А вот что вы хотите получить - не очевидно.

Comment: Я вам сказал, как использовать параметры - `?param1=value1&param2=value2`, а то что вы назвали параметрами - ими не является, а чем является и почему - я выше написал. Ошибка либо в терминологии, либо в понимании вами, что для чего нужно. Скорее всего и вопрос возник из ошибки в этом самом понимании. Как итог, ваш вопрос - [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567).

Comment: Да куда конкретнее то? Вопрос в том как сделать что бы те ссылки со списка обрабатывались в одном контролере и в одном экшене.   /RND/ /123/ /abc/ это  все имена сущностей в бд. Например переходим по /RND/ берется сущность с именем RND и обрабатывается.

Comment: То есть, вы хотите бесконечно длинный путь? Зачем это нужно? Я больше 3-4 слагов `/` в пути не видел нигде. Или не бесконечный, то сколько уровней вложения у вас планируется?

Comment: Ну теоретический может быть длинным а на практике нет. Просто нужно определить маршрут так что бы разные ссылки для которых нет контроллера обрабатывались все в одном контролере и экшене

Comment: `Просто нужно определить маршрут так что бы разные ссылки для которых нет контроллера обрабатывались все в одном контролере` Ну об этом очень хорошо в документации разжевано. [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)